# VUE Trailing path queries

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a query language optional functionality. Where if user goes to

localhost/#/, it would redirect to localhost/#/?lang=en (default is english), changing site's langauge along the way.

If the user goes to /localhost/#/?lang=es, it would display the home page in Hispanic and if from there user would go to any other path it would trail that ?lang=es to all pages.

This is what I currently have in place, however it doesn't work fully:
`
My router:

this code

```
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let lang = from.query.lang;

     //Changing language 
     i18n.locale = lang || 'en';

  //This now should redirect
  if(!lang){
    lang = 'en';
    console.log('Trying to push path: '+to.path+'/?lang='+lang)

    next({ path: `${to.path}/?lang=${lang}` });
    return; 
  }
```

results in

Trying to push path: //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////?lang=en
vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1905 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect to another route inside a router guard, you need to call next() with the new params.

See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards

Specifically:

> Blockquote
>   next('/') or next({ path: '/' }): redirect to a different location. The current navigation will be aborted and a new one will be started. You can pass any location object to next, which allows you to specify options like replace: true, name: 'home' and any option used in router-link's to prop or router.push

So something like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let lang = from.query.lang;
  //Changing language 
  i18n.locale = lang || 'en';

  //This now should redirect
  if(!lang){
    console.log('Trying to push path: '+to.path+'/?lang='+lang)
    next({ path: `${to.path}/?lang=${lang}` });
    return; // this is needed just to make sure code below this get
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you try with ```next({ path: `/${to.path}/?lang=${lang}` });```  (note the / at the beginning) ?

Comment: Can you try instead with ```next({ query: { lang: lang }, replace: true })``` . Sorry but I can't try the code now.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work in fact, it locks the whole project, making it impossible to even login, I also tried this.$router.push({ query: { lang: this.language }}); It works from Vue files but not in beforeEach